# numpy concatenate row vector

Tags: numpy, concatenation

I would need to concatenate 2 row vector into a large row vector with concatenate, 
in my code with numpy 1.9.1, I have something like:

```
print ("new_vector is ",repr(new_vector))
print ("np.zeros((self.N_corr))",repr(np.zeros((self.N_corr))) )
print ("np.concatenate((new_vector,np.zeros((self.N_corr))),axis=1) is ",
        np.concatenate((new_vector,np.zeros((self.N_corr))),axis=1) )

G_3_new_line=np.concatenate((new_vector,np.zeros((self.N_corr))),axis=1)
```

then everything is correct with:

```
('new_vector is ', 'array([ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , -0.01262626,  0.00757576,\n        0.03030303, -0.01515152,  0.        ,  0.03030303, -0.01515152,\n        0.00757576,  0.03030303,  0.01515152,  0.03030303, -0.0145202 ,\n       -0.01515152,  0.00757576,  0.03030303, -0.01515152,  0.        ,\n        0.03030303, -0.0145202 ,  0.00694444,  0.0290404 , -0.21528928])')
('np.zeros((self.N_corr))', 'array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,\n        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])')
('np.concatenate((new_vector,np.zeros((self.N_corr))),axis=1) is ', array([ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , -0.01262626,  0.00757576,
        0.03030303, -0.01515152,  0.        ,  0.03030303, -0.01515152,
        0.00757576,  0.03030303,  0.01515152,  0.03030303, -0.0145202 ,
       -0.01515152,  0.00757576,  0.03030303, -0.01515152,  0.        ,
        0.03030303, -0.0145202 ,  0.00694444,  0.0290404 , -0.21528928,
        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]))
```

But my colleague, while trying to run the same script, have error:

```
      ('new_vector is ', 'array([ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , -0.01262626,  0.00757576,\n        0.03030303, -0.01515152,  0.        ,  0.03030303, -0.01515152,\n        0.00757576,  0.03030303,  0.01515152,  0.03030303, -0.0145202 ,\n       -0.01515152,  0.00757576,  0.03030303, -0.01515152,  0.        ,\n        0.03030303, -0.0145202 ,  0.00694444,  0.0290404 , -0.21528928])')
('np.zeros((self.N_corr))', 'array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,\n        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])')
File "/Users/AAA/repos/my_stuff/fluorinated_rocksalts/cluster_expansion/Co/test_BBB/eci_fit.py", line 415, in _calc_ecis
        ,np.concatenate((new_vector,np.zeros((self.N_corr))),axis=1))
IndexError: axis 1 out of bounds [0, 1)
```

He is running with numpy 1.11... But is this a numpy problem where one version works and not the other? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that when your colleague runs the code `new_vector` or `np.zeros((self.N_corr))` has dimension `(n,)` meaning one dimension.  In order to use `axis=1` with `np.concatenate`, all arrays being concatenated must have a second dimension.  So the code may be the same, but the setup of the vectors is not.  You can add a dimension in several ways.  The easiest is to

```
new_vector[:, None]
```

I can't assume much more.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

On my system ('1.11.0') I get the same error:

```
In [47]: np.concatenate((np.arange(3),np.zeros((3))),axis=1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-2b11cbfcb685> in <module>()
----> 1 np.concatenate((np.arange(3),np.zeros((3))),axis=1)

IndexError: axis 1 out of bounds [0, 1)
```

What surprises me is that you, on your old one, didn't get the same error.  It's possible that some error checking has been added that I'm not aware of.  But my understanding is that this sort of concatenation has always been wrong.  1d arrays have only one axis, 0.

===================

I found a closed issue and pull request on numpy github:

```
BUG: allow any axis for np.concatenate for 1D #440
```

Old versions of `numpy` ignored the axis parameter when the arrays were 1d.  Starting in 1.7 they started to issue a

> This raises a FutureWarning for axis numbers != 0, but allows them, for
>   backwards compatibility.

But warnings normally only appear the first time they arise in a session, and can be turned off.  Apparently in 1.11 this issue raises an error, not just a warning.